# Program efficiency: Algorithm vs Implementation

Tags: algorithm, terminology, implementation

I was watching a lecture about program efficiency where the professor said:

"If I measure running time, it will certainly vary as the algorithm change. (...) But one of the problems is that it will also vary as a function of the implementation (...) If I use a loop that's got a couple of more steps inside of it in one algorithm than another, it's going to change the time."

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the implementation's influence.

So my question is: Why can't we consider those extra loop steps inside of one algorithm, when compared to the other, simply something that is necessary for it to run and that is also a part of the algorithm's efficiency? Or did I completely miss the point here?

Thank you!

Comment: I think they are just explaining the difference between time complexity and running time. You can implement an algorithm in two ways such that they both are O(n) yet one takes twice as long to run as the other. Still they both run in linear time.

Comment: They are also mentioning the difference between "algorithm" and "specific code written in a programming language". "Algorithm" is somewhat of a vague term and "algorithms" are often described in pseudo-code that can be either very detailed, or not detailed at all.

Comment: For instance, an algorithm to test whether a number `n` is prime is to check whether it has any divisor between 2 and its square root. How exactly do you loop over the numbers between 2 and the square root? You could do `s = sqrt(n); for (d = 2; d <= s; d++) ...` or `for (d = 2; d*d <= n; d++)`. Those two codes might not have exactly the same runtime, since the former requires computing `sqrt(n)` once, but the latter requires computing `d*d` at every iteration in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are pointing out the difference between "algorithm" and "specific code written in a programming language". "Algorithm" is somewhat of a vague term and "algorithms" are often described in pseudo-code that can be either very detailed, or not detailed at all.

For instance, consider the following algorithm, to test whether a number `n` is prime or not:

- If any number `d` between 2 and the square root of `n` divides `n`:
- Return False (`n` is not prime)
- Else:
- Return True (`n` is prime)

How exactly do you loop over the numbers between 2 and the square root? You could do:

```cpp
// IMPLEMENTATION A

bool is_prime(int n)
{
    int s = sqrt(n);
    for (int d = 2; d <= s; d++)
    {
        if (n % d == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

or:

```cpp
// IMPLEMENTATION B

bool is_prime(int n)
{
    for (int d = 2; d * d <= n; d++)
    {
        if (n % d == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Those two codes both implement the algorithm that I described. However, they might not have exactly the same runtime, since the former requires computing `sqrt(n)` once, but the latter requires computing `d * d` at every iteration in the loop.

Computer scientists want to be able to discuss the complexity of the algorithm that I described above in pseudo-code. And they don't want someone to give the boring answer "Sorry, the complexity of that algorithm is impossible to calculate, because we don't know if it's implementation A or implementation B".